# Raspberry Pi Zero w/NOOBs preloaded SDcard with Ricos OS selected Boot problem

Tags: sd-card, power-supply, pi-zero-w

When I power up Pi Zero, I get to the page to boot into safe mode and the screen goes black for a few seconds and then flashes and shows four colored squares in the top right corner of my screen. If I try and press shift to boot into recovery it does the same thing. I have not seen this issue before is it my SD card or possibly a power problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem was due to a bad power supply. I turned it on with nothing pluged in and it worked. I swithched to a better power supply and now it works even with the dongle pluged in on start up.